# usar handle na textView

Tags: android-studio, thread, handler

Estou criando um chatbot e quero que quando eu enviar algo, apareça em uma textview  a mensagem 'pensando...' durante 5 segundos antes de enviar a resposta, já estudei sobre Handler, mas até agora não tive nenhuma ideia de como fazer isso, alguém tem alguma ideia por aí?

Comment: Poderia nos mostrar a parte relevante do seu código até agora? Isso facilita a nossa análise e aumenta a possibilidade de você obter ajuda. Veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como não foi colocado nenhum código para analisarmos, segue um modelo genérico para que você possa adaptar rapidamente a sua realidade:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class MinhaClasse extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tela_minha_tela);

//insira o código aqui que será execultado antes dos 5 segundos


Handler handler = new Handler(); //classe para contagem de tempo
handler.postDelayed(this, 5000); //5000 = 5 segundos

}

@Override
    public void run() {
//Aqui ficará o código que será executado após 5 segundos 

}
}
```